# Empty view in list View in xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view in my xamarin app and I need to put an option that when the list is empty, in the collection view we have `<CollectionView.EmptyView>` but when I search for list view there is no option for it and it's more complex, so, there is a quick fix or not? and what is the there standard solution for it ?

Comment: Why not use CollectionView instead?

Comment: If you are unable to use CollectionView, here's how I've tackled this way back in the day. Put your ListView and your EmptyView in a container that allows views to stack, such as a Grid or AbsoluteLayout. Set the EmptyView to visible when the collection is NullOrEmpty, and set the ListView to Visible when the collection !NullOrEmpty. You can write your own converter for this, or I think that the Xamarin Community Toolkit has one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,`CollectionView` is a better choice for [empty view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/emptyview).However, if you insist on using listivew to achieve empty view effect,you could use this package `Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfListView`.Just binding `IsVisible` property when the listview is empty like below,for more details please refer to this [repo](https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/How-to-show-empty-message-when-listview-has-no-items-in-xamarin-forms).

```
      <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="ItemSource" Grid.Row="0" 
                Text="Change ItemSource" 
                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                Command="{Binding ChangeItemsSource}"/>
        <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" Grid.Row="1">
            <Label x:Name="label"
                   Text = "No Items :(" />
        </Grid>
        <sync:SfListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsInfo}"
                         IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
                         ItemSize="30">
            <sync:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding ContactName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sync:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        </sync:SfListView>
    </Grid>
```

Official reference link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/emptyview